# How to search PCP by date created?

Tags: pcp, personal-campaign-pages

Is there any way to search Personal Campaign Pages by the date that the campaign is created? On /civicrm/admin/pcp page, you can sort by starts and end dates, but these are for the donation/event pages, not the campaign page itself.

So for example, I created a campaign page in February 2016 for an event which is open since July 2014. Is there a way to find all campaign pages that are created in February 2016?

Answer (score 1):

Great idea. Unfortunately there is currently no way to do this.

Personal campaign pages don't even *store* the date that they were created.

Enabling database-level logging would allow you to store this type of data, but you would need to build a custom search or report to see it.

I agree this would be a great feature though!